# Typescript type-queries in classes

Tags: typescript

I am trying to get typescript type-queries to work in classes.

Normally type-queries work like this:

```
const user = { name: "Patrick", age: 17 };
let typeofUser: typeof user;
```

In the example above the "typeofUser" would have the the type:

```
{ name: string, age: number }
```

So far so good. But I'm trying to get type-queries to work with classes.
For example:

```
class App {
  states = {
    menu: {
      login() {
        console.log("Menu.login");
      }
    },
    game: {
      update() {
        console.log("Game.update");
      }
    }
  };

  constructor() {
    // FAILS => Cannot find name "states"
    const typeofStates: typeof states = {};

    // FAILS => Cannot find name "states"
    const keyofStates: keyof states = "game";
  }
}
```

My question is: How can I access class members for type-queries,
with eighter the "typeof" or "keyof" operator?

[Typescript playground sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2F%20DOES%20NOT%20WORK%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20App%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20states%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20menu%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20login()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Menu.login%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20game%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20update()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Game.update%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20typeofStates%3A%20typeof%20states%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20keyofStates%3A%20keyof%20states%20%3D%20%22game%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20DOES%20WORK%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20x%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20hello%3A%20%22world%22%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20typeofX%3A%20typeof%20x%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20hello%3A%20%22%22%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A)

Comment: `typeof App.prototype.states` and `keyof typeof App.prototype.states`.

Comment: `App['states']` and `keyof App['states']`

Comment: Both of these solutions work, may someone of you suggest your answers as an answer to the question, so I can accept them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @cartant in the comments. I'm answering this question myself since he did not post his comment as a answer.

---

To type-query the type of a class member you can use several methods:

- Access the prototype:

  ```
  App.prototype.states
  ```
- Access it via a indexer

  ```
  App["states"]
  ```

  > A important thing to note is that this and the above method may not work when the member is private or static.
- The polymorphic this type

  Everything that has a this in Javascript has a "this type" in typescript. This "this" type can be queried like every other index type.

  ```
  this["states"]
  ```

  > Note: You may have issues when using this technique when trying to call a function in another context. Also you **cannot** use the dot operator! You must use the object index operator instead

The this type-query is very useful in combination with class-inheritance

If you were to Programm a Statemachine for example you could have a abstract "Statemachine" Class and use the this-type-query to get the type of a property in the child class

This may look like this:

```
abstract class Statemachine {
  /* The typescript compiler won't actually infer "object" but 
    {
       menu: { 
         login() => void
       },
       game: {
         update() => void 
       }
    }

    > In case of the example below! 
  */
  abstract states: object

  getState<K extends keyof this["states"]>(name: K): T[K] {
    return this.states[name];
  }
}

class Game extends Statemachine {
  private states = {
     menu: {
       login() {
         console.log("Menu.login")
       }
     },
     game: {
       update() {
         console.log("Game.update") }
      }
   }
}

const game = new Game()

// Compiler error
game.getState("not a key of game.states")

// Works and intellisense for login()
game.getState("menu")
```

Reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html
Look for polymorphic this.

I hope the code actually works Im on vacation and had no chance to check it...